# Grafana worldmap: table datasource

Tags: grafana

I am trying to use the worldmap plugin of grafana with table data as datasource (in my case influxdb) which got supported with the newest version. [link](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-worldmap-panel)

But sadly I am not able to get it working. I use the same query as in the docu of the plugin but no points are shown in my worldmap. Here are the screenshots of my query:

[image]

[image]

This is a example how I insert into influxdb:

```
json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": measurement,
            "tags": {
                "host": host,
                "geohash": geohash
            },
            "fields": {
                "metric": 1
            }
        }
    ]
```

It would be really happy if some1 can point me to my problem here.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I changed field(value) to field(metric) now it seems to work. But Thank you for your help @DanielLee and for your great panel ;)

Comment: Now that you say it, it's obvious. But I totally missed it too.

Comment: @DanielLee is the select querry of the Readme I linked wrong too then ? Since it shows field(value) and alias(metric) like I had.

Comment: The field in the sample data used for that query was called value whereas your field is called metric. I think I had better add a note about that in the readme :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I was able to use the worldmap panel with a table datasource from influxdb:

The table data:

```
{
    "measurement": "ghash",
    "tags": {
        "host": host,
        "geohash": geohash
    },
    "fields": {
        "value": 1
    }
}
```

The query inside Grafana:

[image]

Worldmap tab:

[image]

Comment: @marc_s what is the host here?

Comment: @Luv33preet just a String! like "host_123"

Comment: and geohash is the geohash value of lat lng ? and what is value?

Comment: @Luv33preet "u08zxwq" for example

Comment: You mistook it, I know about geohash's value, but I wanted to know about `"fields":{"value":1}` , this value, will it always be 1?

Comment: @Luv33preet if you take a look at the worldmap plugin you will see that the circles are formatted/sized due to their value. For example a circle with value 1 will be smaller/different color than a circle with value 100. For my case, I always set value 1 to have equal sized circles with equal color

Comment: okay, one more thing, `select field(value) count() alias(value)` in the grafana query, I am doing like this `select field(*)` and there is no difference in the map. Why you advised  `select field(value) count() alias(value)` this then?

Comment: @Luv33preet Because select field(*) selects everything and I don't want to select everything. Just think about the case you add some new fields to your series in the future. You will have to recheck all your dashboards if something changed in an unwanted way. (Just a best practice tip)

Comment: anything about that threshold value option in Grafana's WorldMap Panel, I am changing values, but the color remains the same?

Comment: @Luv33preet In case you have problems not related to this answer please open another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139130/discussion-between-luv33preet-and-iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii).