# How to present tag value in table using grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I want to present **tag value** in table using Grafana connected with influxDB and I'm wondering if it is possible ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Here's an example of a query for a table panel from the Grafana demo site which groups by tag: http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-issue-4204?panelId=3&fullscreen&edit

Comment: No error. The problem is that I want to show only tag values, but I can not SELECT tag values, only fields.

Comment: Usually tag values are used in the GROUP BY. Maybe you can take a screenshot of your query and provide an example of the data?

Answer (score 6):

To add to @Pawel's answer: Select one field, set format as Table AND Group By all the tags you want to display in the table.

Answer (score 2):

To show Tag value in grafana table it is essential to use at least **one** field in SELECT and set format as : Table.

Comment: Great that you could solve your problem. If you spend a bit more time on your question then you will get better answers. Next time start with a screenshot of your query and some sample data - here's a good example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218814/grafana-worldmap-table-datasource

Comment: I have the same problem I was able to understand your question, but not your answer. Also does the answer depend on the datasource being used? (you mention SELECT, does that mean you're using SQL datasource? If so I wounder if your solution is datasource specific.)
What was your datasource? What was your Query? Visualization is table, but what about Table Transform, Columns, and settings. Also Daniel's right screenshots are great especially since Grafana UI and verbage can change between versions. O that reminds me it'd also be good to say what version of Grafana an answer is applicable to.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "<table_name>" with Key= "<tag_name>" WHERE ("tag_name"='Internal')`

This will give two column keys with tag_name and value will be your tag value. 
In visualization settings, you can hide key.