# Grafana worldmap panel with Influxdb doesn't show points

Tags: influxdb, grafana, world-map

I installed Worldmap Panel for Grafana but I cannot display points on Worldmap Panel. I looked at 
[Grafana worldmap: table datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218814/grafana-worldmap-table-datasource)
and other links but didn't find answer.
I tried to use countries.json : 
Added [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YNBk.png)
I don't have reputation 10 so I cannot add more than 2 links. I tried also create table : `points,key=AL,name=Alabama,latitude=32.7990 longitude=-86.8073`
and in Worldmap selected for Location Data : `table`, for Table Label Field : `points` but still cannot see points.
Could you please give an idea for any possible solutions : countries, states, geohash, json, jsonp or table to be able to see points for Worldmap Panel?
Thank you

Comment: in which datasoruce you created the table ?

Comment: Saw that you posted on the Grafana group too with more screenshots: https://groups.io/g/grafana/message/2171 but it's still hard to see what the datasource is? One of the screenshots shows the Test(fake) datasource and that won't work with Worldmap as its data does not have  country codes or geohashes.

Comment: The answer from @MarkB is the only way to use WorldMap with InfluxDb right now. You have to use Geohashes. Don't have support for InfluxDb/Table Data and Country Codes yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for precision about Geohashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I recognize with your table data is, that you provide the coordinates as **latitude,longitude** but you need to provide them as **geohash**.

As you are asking for any possible solution I am providing you my solution with influxdb:

1) Insert into influxdb:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'worldmap_test,host=server01,geohash=gbsuv7z value=1'
```

2) Set datasource in grafana to your influxdb database

3) Now in the worldmap panel set the created datasouce and use the following metric:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I figured out that Worldmap can match country codes in Influx Db.

1. Choose the country code tag in the group by.
2. Alias it with `$tag_tagname` where `tagname` is the country code tag name.
3. Choose `Format as Time Series`
4. On the Worldmap tab, choose Location Data -> Countries

[image]

[image]