# Grafana worldmap didn't show points

Tags: grafana

I failed to use Grafana worldmap to show my geohash points.
Please help.

Grafana version: 1.7.9

Ubuntu 16.04.06

1. insert a point to influxdb

   $ curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'worldmap_test,host=server01,geohash=gbsuv7z value=1'
2. make sure the point is in the DB
   [image]
3. In grafana, try to use table panel and query the data is no problem
   [image]
4. Switch to use worldmap panel. Can't see any point. :~
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: I followed this but not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154884/grafana-worldmap-panel-with-influxdb-doesnt-show-points

Answer (score 0):

Ohoh... Finally, I upgraded grafana to 6.4.4 and it works now. :)