# How can I render time-series data on a geographic display in grafana?

Tags: devops, grafana, geomap

My goal is to render time-series data from set locations on a map. Essentially, I have about 30 predefined (static) locations in Switzerland from which I will be receiving real-time data. The data itself is relatively simple, just the signal/noise ratio of the signal we're receiving, which should be updated every few seconds or every minute. I am using InfluxDB as my database. Are there any specific setups I should be using for this kind of visualization?

My first question is: is it best to use the worldmap panel or the geomap panel at this time? I seem to be finding more information/documentation on the worldmap panel even though i have also read that geomap is (or at least will be) its replacement.

Second, I assume that since I'm using time-series data, that I should be using the Time-Series format, and not the Table format. However, I have not been able to render any data points using the time-series feature, even by following the simplest of examples in your documentation. The best I can do is use the Table feature, and internally remove previous points from my database at every iteration (so that multiple points aren't rendered at the same time for each location). Here are two screenshots of when I'm able to render data on the geomap using the Table format, and then after switching to Time-Series format that the points are no longer there (note that I have the same problem with the Worldmap application as well).

I'm able to render data using the Table method:

[image: table method]

...but not using time series:

[image: time series method]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For rendering timeseries data on the geomap, you must convert your lat/long fields to a single geohash field. You'll have to do that prior to inserting the lat/longs into influxDB

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39160812/18144909)

Comment: Can you add more details?